# How to use the DataGrid control with SQLiteDataReader?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagrid, compact-framework

I am developing mobile application in C#. I want to read the values from the database & display in the gridview control. I am not aware of of how to use the SQLiteDataReader with datagrid control in compact framework. My code is running properly but I am not able to display the values in the datagrid

```
SQLiteDataReader SQLiteDrKeyObj = null;
            DataManager DataMgrObj = new DataManager();
            QueryDetails QueryDetailsObj = new QueryDetails();
            int KeyID = Cust_ID;
            string Client_Key1 = Client_Key;
            SQLiteDrKeyObj = DataMgrObj.getRegistrationKey(KeyID, Client_Key); 
            RegKeyInfodataGrid.DataSource = SQLiteDrKeyObj;
```

Can you please provide me the code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Comment: SQLiteDataReader SQLiteDrKeyObj = null;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataManager DataMgrObj = new DataManager();
            QueryDetails QueryDetailsObj = new QueryDetails();
            int KeyID = Cust_ID;
            string Client_Key1 = Client_Key;
            SQLiteDrKeyObj = DataMgrObj.getRegistrationKey(KeyID, Client_Key);
            dt.Load(SQLiteDrKeyObj);
            
            RegKeyInfodataGrid.DataSource = dt;
            RegKeyInfodataGrid.SuspendLayout();

Comment: I have solved the above issue by using the above code. But i want to resize the datagrid control or the datatable control so that all the data will be displayed properly. How to do this ?